# Замена макросов python

Tags: python

Добрый день!
В субботний день голова думает не на нужном уровне :)

Не могу разобраться - как в тексте подменить макрос на результат выполненного кода, к примеру, имеется текст с макросами:

```
text = 'Date: [RAND-1-31]-[RAND-1-12]-20[RAND-11-12], [RAND-1-12]:[RAND-1-5][RAND-1-9] PM'
```

Каким образом можно пройтись по всем этим макросам и заменить их результатом выполнения функции randint(a,b)? Думаю решение где-то на поверхности, но ко мне оно не приходит :)
Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

re.sub и заменять на результат работы функции, которая на [RAND-1-31] выдаёт результат str(randint(1, 31))

```
def fun(m):
    return str(random.randint(int(m.group(1)), int(m.group(2))))
t = re.sub(r'\[RAND-(\d+)-(\d+)\]', fun, text)
```

или

```
t = re.sub(r'\[RAND-(\d+)-(\d+)\]', lambda m: str(random.randint(int(m.group(1)), int(m.group(2)))), text)
```

**UPD** Исправлена ошибка в первой группе: `(\d+)`. Было `(\d)+` (см. комментарий @xenoll)

Comment: Все работает, возьму на заметку. Только если кто-то еще будет использовать этот код - то нужно подправить регулярку r'\[RAND-(\d+)-(\d+)\]'
Спасибо!